# "Attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference" when trying to startActivityForResult from activity sublass

Tags: java, android

I'm writing a plugin for an app in which I need to create a dialog window that allows users to take a photo for later use. I don't access to the main activity of the app to use onActivityResult, so I'm trying to create a activity sublass with onActivityResult to call startActivityForResu

```
public class UserAddDialog {

    private AlertDialog dialog;
    private View dialogView;

    private ImageView tempPhoto;
    private Context c;

    public UserAddDialog build(final Context context, LayoutInflater inflater) {
        c = context;
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        final Activity act = (Activity) context;
        builder.setTitle("Add person to TLS logbook");
        dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.user_role_layout, null);
        builder.setView(dialogView);
        dialog = builder.create();

        tempPhoto = (ImageView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.takenPic);
        Button takePicture = (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.takePhoto);

        takePicture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;

                Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(act.getPackageManager()) != null) {
                    PictureAct p = new PictureAct();
                    p.startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                }

            }
        });


        return this;
    }

    public void show() {dialog.show();}

    class PictureAct extends Activity {

        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
                tempPhoto.setImageBitmap(photo);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting  `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.app.ActivityThread$ApplicationThread android.app.ActivityThread.getApplicationThread()' on a null object reference`

on the line
`p.startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);`

Any ideas? I also tried to just create an activity instead of doing a dialog, but I need the resulting picture to be used in the apps activity which I can't access from the new activity. I also am using api 29 so I cannot use Fragments since they were deprecated.

Comment: Replace p with the activity context.

Comment: the context of PictureAct? I'm not sure what you mean. Can you give an example?

Answer (score 1):

To start an activity or activityForResult from Activity:

```
startActivityForResult( intent , code );
```

From Fragment:

```
getActivity().startActivityForResult( yourIntent , yourRequestCode);
```

Elsewhere:

```
Activity act = ( Activity ) context;
act.startActivityForResult( intent , code );
```

Comment: getActivity isn't available to the dialog class and I don't believe that would trigger the onActivityResult of PicActivity

Comment: Make the dialog ```extends DialogFragment```

Comment: Or maybe replace getActivity with ```act``` since you already defined it here ```final Activity act = (Activity) context;``` Idk if this would work. Didnt try it.

Comment: I'm successfully starting the activity now, but my problem now is that I can't get onActivityResult working in my class. I'm also having problems making the dialog class a dialogfragment since that also was deprecated in 28

Comment: You need to use ```androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment```